# compare ubuntu alongside windows and ubuntu in a different partition etc

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a question about the speed/performance of Ubuntu when it is

- installed alongside windows, in the same partition
- installed alongside windows, on a different partition.

e.g., I shrunk my primary partition (with Windows inside it), then I created another partition.  Now, when I installed it alongside Windows, I chose the other partition which I had dedicated to Ubuntu.

Are there a speed/performance difference?
Pros and cons?

To share my experience: I experienced some kind of delay, when I installed it alongside Windows on a different partition(partition A=Windows , partition B=Ubuntu)

How can I solve this lagging issue?

(there is nothing installed yet on my Windows 7, and on my Ubuntu, I installed Monodevelop,and some updates)

Comment: I can think of no reason why ubuntu should be slower on another partition. Are you *sure* `B` wasn't on another slower disk? Anyway it's a *baad* idea to have ubuntu (or anything else) installed on the same partition as windows.

Answer (score 0):

The only practical disadvantage to using Wubi is that it's a bit harder to add space to Ubuntu's drive when you need it. But it is possible.

Theoretically and in practice there isn't much if a speed hump. In effect Ubuntu under Windows simply creates a virtual disk on the Windows partition and mounts that. The speed difference is negligible unless you're really pushing the edge.

Comment: why am i experiencing lag? is it the method of installation?

Comment: Probably you have something lurking in there. Try using BleachBit and deleting some stuff.